# ¿Porque no me deja hacer la autenticacion con el token Bearer?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, express, jwt

¿cómo están?, He estado haciendo un CRUD con el stack MEAN, y hasta ahorita voy en la parte del backend del software, lo que he intentado es hacer una autenticación simple usando JWT y Bearer, pero no he conseguido resolver el problema me sale Cannot GET /user/privateDiary en el postman. He estado siguiendo el siguiente  [tutorial para crear CRUD del STACK MEAN](https://youtu.be/rPD0eY3dRqQ?t=2315)

Aqui les muestro las routes del software

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require("../controllers/userController");


//log in an administrator
router.post("/login", userController.login);

router.get("/privateDiary", userController.privateDiary);


module.exports = router;
```

Aqui esta el Controller

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const userSchema = require("../models/user");

//log in an administrator
module.exports.login = async(req, res) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await userSchema.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) return res.status(401).send("The email doesn't exists");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword)
        return res.status(401).send("Wrong Password");

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, "secretkey");

    return res.status(200).json({
        data: "welcome success",
        token,
    });
};


module.exports.privateDiary = (verifyToken),
    async(req, res) => {
        res.json([{
                _id: "1",
                name: "task one",
                description: "asdadasd",
                date: "2019-11-06T15:50:18.921Z",
            },
            {
                _id: "2",
                name: "task two",
                description: "asdadasd",
                date: "2019-11-06T15:50:18.921Z",
            },
            {
                _id: "3",
                name: "task three",
                description: "asdadasd",
                date: "2019-11-06T15:50:18.921Z",
            },
        ]);
    };


async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    try {
        if (!req.headers.authorization) {
            return res.status(401).send("Unauhtorized Request 1");
        }
        let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        if (token === "null") {
            return res.status(401).send("Unauhtorized Request 2");
        }

        const payload = await jwt.verify(token, "secretkey");
        if (!payload) {
            return res.status(401).send("Unauhtorized Request 3");
        }
        req.userId = payload._id;
        next();
    } catch (e) {
        //console.log(e)
        return res.status(401).send("Unauhtorized Request 4");
    }

}
```

Index.js del SW

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const db = require("./db");

//routes
const user = require("./routes/user");

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

//app.use
app.use("/user", user);


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    respuesta = {
        error: true,
        codigo: 200,
        mensaje: "Inital Point",
    };
    res.send(respuesta);
});

let respuesta = {
    error: false,
    codigo: 200,
    mensaje: "Err",
};


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(
        "The Server is Initialized on Port 3000, http://localhost:3000 "
    );
});
```

Modelo user.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

//hashing password using bcrypt
userSchema.methods.encryptClave = async(password) => {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("admn", userSchema);
```

[image: Cannot GET /user/privateDiary]

Lo que he intenado es quitar el `.split(" ")[1];` del verifyToken pero me muestra Unauhtorized Request que me recomiendan hacer, ayuda, Gracias :D

[image: Unauhtorized Request]

Comment: Podrás subir el server o index.js, quizás es un tema de orden.

Comment: listo ya lo subi

Comment: Hay varias cosas que yo cambiaría, pero lo primero que debes hacer es asegurarte de que estás entrando en la ruta, porque decirte que no se pudo hacer la llamada a get users/privateDiary y decirte unauthorized son cosas muy diferentes.. Una vez que hayas asegurado que entras en la ruta con un simple console.log en la primer linea dentro del callback de la ruta, ahí eliminaría todo el verify y usaría directamente check-jwt, es un middleware muy sencillo, hace toda la comprobación y te deja la data automáticamente disponible en todas las rutas en req.user

Comment: Por otro lado si no me equivoco el jwt.verify ahora te exige que definas el algoritmo. Fijate que el tutorial no sea antiguo...

Comment: es mejor usar este?, la verdad no te entendi muy bien, soy novato :/ : https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Comment: Ya entre a la ruta y ahora me aparace unauthorized

Comment: Ahora podrías identificar en cual de todos los if está entrando, eso te ayudará a orientarte al problema ... Una forma fácil es agregar un número diferente a cada mensaje de unauthorized y ver dónde está explotando.

Comment: se esta explotando en el primer if este (le agrege numeros para identificarlos mejor):               

if (!req.headers.authorization) {
            return res.status(401).send("Unauhtorized Request 1");
        }
                         
.Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Hacé un console.log de req.headers.authorization antes del if, si eso no te llegue jamás funcionará la validación.. y dejá Authorization en postman con mayúscula nomás.

Comment: cuando le quito el .split(" ")[1]; me lanza Unauhtorized Request 4, pero al ingresar la ruta en la web "http://localhost:3000/user/privateDiary" aparece Unauhtorized Request 1, que raro no?

Comment: Es porque al quitar el split se lee un string que tiene "Bearer + el token" entonces no puede validarlo, por eso el split separa Bearer y el token en 2 pociones de un array y ahí accedes con la posición 1, mediante [1]. Esto sugiere que hay un toquen, hace el console.log de los headers.authorization y fijate que te trae.

Comment: Pues le coloque el  .split(" ")[1]; y me aparece lo siguiente en consola con headers.authorization: en el postman me muestra el "Bearer + el token" , pero al recargar en el enlace "localhost:3000/user/privateDiary" me aperece  undefined

Comment: En postman prueba borrar el key y value de los headers, ve a la pestaña Authorization, a la izquierda en type marca bearer y a la derecha pon el token, luego has un console.log antes del if en el controlador de req.headers y fijate como te viene y si viene el token.

Comment: sigue igual, en el postman me muestra el "Bearer + el token" , pero al recargar en el enlace "localhost:3000/user/privateDiary" me aperece undefined

Comment: Es muy difícil solucionar así, quizás si podés subir tu proyecto a un repo puedo bajar una copia y probarlo. No tiene mucho sentido lo que te está sucediendo...

Comment: mira aqui te paso el repo: https://github.com/JuanfelipeX/CV-Angular   gracias por tu colaboracion, espero que me puedas ayudar :), le acabe de hacer un push

Comment: Yo personalmente nunca habia visto definir un controlador de esa manera tan extraña: `module.exports.privateDiary = (verifyToken),async(req, res) => { ... }` o yo desconozco algo, o eso está mal definido. Si tu intencion es usar el `verifyToken` como middleware, debes meterlo es en la definicion de la ruta: `router.get("/privateDiary", verifyToken, userController.privateDiary);` y `privateDiary = async (req,res) => { ... }`

Comment: hice lo que me dijistes pero, me aparece igual en el postman me muestra el "Bearer + el token" , pero al recargar en el enlace "localhost:3000/user/privateDiary" me aperece undefined